# How to implement 2 functions for the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

To gain a better understanding at algorithms and to write more structured I have some assignments to split one algorithm into two functions. But I still struggle how to connect everything. I have here my implemented algorithm of the Sieve of Eratosthenes but it gives me two errors

> Unsolved reference 'prime'

In what way can I divide this properly over two functions - 1. To cross out the numbers that are a prime (True) and not a prime (False, who are all multiples of n) 2. The function that returns the list of all primes below n.

This is what I have now.

```
def label(prime, n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)):
        prime = True

    if prime[0] and prime[1]:
        is_prime = False

    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        for j in range(2 * i, n + 1, i):
            prime[j] = False

    return prime


def sieve(n):
    arr = label(prime, n)
    for i in range(n+1):
        if arr[i]:
            return i
```

**EDIT** 
My code was indeed unclear. I changed it a bit, but I still don't quite understand how to pass from one function to another, hence the "unsolved reference 'prime' error".

```
def label(prime, n):
    prime = [True for _ in range(n+1)]
    prime[0], prime[1] = False, False

    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        for j in range(2*i, n+1, i):
            prime[j] = False

    return prime


def sieve(n):
    arr = label(prime, n)
    for i in range(n+1):
        if arr[i]:
            return i
```

Comment: You have the line `arr = label(prime, n)` but you never defined `prime` within `sieve` or in the global scope. So why do you expect that there _wouldn't_ be an error about that variable missing?

Comment: That makes sense of course but if I declare it in the second function too it tells me to get rid of it because "parameter prime value is not used"

Comment: Your code just doesn't make sense to me. You have `prime = True` which tells me that it is a boolean, but then you have `if prime[0] and prime[1]`, and `prime[j] = False` which treats it like a list. You never instantiated `prime` as a list, and you never add items to it, meaning that trying to access `prime[0]` or `prime[1]` will result in an error since there are no items in the list. But it's not even a list because you set it to a bool via `prime = True`. Did you maybe mean to do `prime.append(True)`?

Comment: It seems like you want `prime` to store a list of values stating whether or not a value at that index is prime. Since lists are passed by reference in Python, that means if you make a list via `prime = []`, then pass `prime` to `label` via `label(prime, n)`, then you can just check `if prime[i]` rather than creating `arr`, which points to the same copy of the same list as `prime`. Therefore, you don't even need to `return prime` from `label`. Also in `label` you set `is_prime = False`, but you never use `is_prime` anywhere else. There's just a lot going on here.

Comment: Rather than building the list of primes every time, by the way, it's useful to instead store a global set of values that contains all the primes, so you don't have to rebuild it every time. This is called "memoization".

Comment: Also your `for j in range(2 * i, n + 1, i)` loop stops at `n + 1`, meaning you're trying to add an item to `prime[n + 1]`. And yet your `for i in range(2, int(n**0.5))` loop only stops at `n**0.5`, meaning that there would be far fewer items in `prime` than `n + 1`. And that's if you made it so that the `for i in range(2, int(n**0.5))` added items to `prime`; it does not, though. This means that `prime[j] = False` would throw an error about the list index being out of range. Perhaps you think that you can assign to any index of `prime` even if that item doesn't exist? That's not the case.

Comment: I really think you need to take a step back, work this all out on paper, have a very clear idea in your head of how this will work step-by-step, and then translate those thoughts into code. You can't easily design a program on-the-fly. You usually need to have a clear design in mind beforehand, and even be able to graph everything on a flow chart without even thinking about how it'd be implemented in code.

Comment: Thanks for being so kind to help. I'm trying to get a grip of what you are trying to point out. The main thing is that I'd want to split up the different processes:
- Implementing a function `label` that takes as arguments a list of boolean values (true/false) name `prime` and a number n. The function sets the boolean values at all multiples of n (2*n, 3*n, 4*n ...) that are in the list to false.
- Implementing a function sieve(n)  which gives back a list of all primes below n.

Comment: Just remove the *parameter* `prime`. It should only be a local variable in the function `label`. The caller will get it as return value. It shouldn't have to pass it as argument.

Comment: Secondly, a `return` in a `for` loop will stop that loop from iterating (obviously). I don't think you want that. Make it a generator and replace that `return` with `yield`.

Comment: @trincot whoops you're right, my bad

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- `prime` is not defined in `sieve`, so it cannot pass it as argument to `label`. Just remove the parameter `prime`. It should only be a local variable in the function `label`. The caller will get it as return value. It shouldn't have to pass it as argument.
- The `return` in the `for` loop will stop the loop from getting further results. That is not what you want. The loop should continue, even after finding the first prime. I would suggest making `sieve` a generator, and then you only have to replace that `return` with `yield`.

With those 2 changes, you can easily print a prime sequence:

```
def label(n):
    prime = [True for _ in range(n+1)]
    prime[0], prime[1] = False, False

    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        for j in range(2*i, n+1, i):
            prime[j] = False

    return prime


def sieve(n):
    arr = label(n)
    for i in range(n+1):
        if arr[i]:
            yield i


# demo
print(*sieve(100))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't think the `return` function through. `yield` is much better indeed. Only the point being that I'm being tested through a test passing both `prime` as well as `n` in the function. So I cannot simply delete the `prime` parameter in the function.

Comment: I don't understand that. From your question I understand that you are the author of `sieve`. `label` is not called by a testing framework, but by your own `sieve` function. Or are you saying that `sieve` function is just your own test, but is not part of the code you must provide? If the testing framework calls `label` directly, then please add information about that in your question. What does it pass as `prime` list then? What is in there? What is `label` supposed to *return*? The exact same thing as is also in `prime`?